# Comparing date columns using sas macros

Tags: sas, macros

I I’m trying to compare two columns, both of which are dates. I know that some are the same so I expect to have some flagged as 1 within the macro. Which I can see when I don’t use the macro. Can anyone help.

```
Data test;
Set source;
*this works;
If date_1=date_2 then do;
X=1;
End;
else do;
X=0;
End;

*this doesnt work;
%macro flags(start=,flag=);
%If &start=date_2 %then %do;
&flag=1;
%End;
%else %do;
&flag=0;
%End;
%mend flags(start=flag_1,flag=x);

Run;
```

I tried to compare columns i was expecting a 1 if dates were the same and 0 if not.

Everything is 0 within a macro but ok if not using one.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the macro code.  Do you really want to test if the string passed in the START parameter is equal to the string `date_2`?  Are you testing to see if the user passed in the right variable name?  You invalid text on the %MEND statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the macro to generate the same data step then make sure that it generates the IF statements also.  You will need to call the macro inside of a data step so that the generated SAS code is run in a valid location.

```
%macro flags(start=,flag=);
if &start=date_2 then do;
  &flag=1;
end;
else do;
  &flag=0;
end;
%mend ;

data test;
  set source;
%flags(start=flag_1,flag=x);
run;
```

PS SAS will evaluate a boolean expression as 1 for true and 0 for false so your code could be reduced to

```
%macro flags(start=,flag=);
&flag = (&start=date_2);
%mend ;
```

Which really does not need to be a macro.

```
data test;
  set source;
  x = (flag_1 = date_2);
run;
```